# Is there a power series for $\text{sech}(x)$ valid for all $x$? Or for $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: power-series, hyperbolic-functions

Is there a power series for $\text{sech}(x)=\frac{2}{e^{-x}+e^{x}}$ that converges for all $x$ or for $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$?  I am familiar with the well known series
\begin{equation}
  \text{sech}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n},
\end{equation}
where the $E_{2n}$ are the Euler numbers.  This series converges for $x^2<\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.  It is interesting that this series stops working at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ considering the power series for $e^x$ converges for all $x$, but it definitely does.

[image]

So is it possible to expand $\text{sech}(x)$ in powers of $x$ beyond $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: There will not be a power series that is valid for all $x$. If there were, $\operatorname{sech}$ would extend to an entire function which it is not as $e^x + e^{-x}$ has zeroes, creating poles in the complex plane. You could make other power series representations, but they will only converge until points where $e^x + e^{-x}$ is zero, i.e. $e^{2x} = -1$. You therefore can't create a power series that will converge on $|x| > \frac{\pi}{2}$. You might have more luck with Laurent series though.

Comment: Not a power series, but there is also [this partial fraction expansion](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Hyperbolic_Secant_Function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no globally convergent power series for sech(x), but you can of course get the taylor series for any specific point.

However there are certain series' of that do converge globally that can be computed efficiently:

Consider that

$$sech(x) = \frac{1}{cosh(x)} = \frac{2}{e^x+e^-x}$$

We can now use the taylor series of cosh(x):

$$sech(x) = \frac{1}{cosh(x)} = \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$

This series also converges extremely quickly.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me an idea.